# How to add background to image in react native?

Tags: react-native

I added a picture and I want to add a background to the image in a fixed size.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

import { Alert, View, Image, StyleSheet , Text , Button, ImageBackground} from 'react-native'

function Test1(props) {

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.container2}>
            <ImageBackground source={require('../assets/plus.jpeg')} resizeMode="cover" style={styles.image4}>
               
            </ImageBackground>  
            </View>
        </View>
        
    );
}

export default Test1;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    image4:{
        //  flex: 1,
          justifyContent: "center",
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
  },
    text4: {
        color: "white",
        fontSize: 42,
        lineHeight: 84,
        fontWeight: "bold",
        textAlign: "center",
        backgroundColor: "#000000c0"
      },
    container2: {
        flex: 1,
    },
  
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#a9a9a9',
        flexDirection:'column',
        alignItems:'center',
        paddingTop: 100,
      }
    

})
```

This is the result that I want ( +- )
[image: current_result]

I want to add another black square to the image ( the default background is gray )
In my case the default image is with white background( and not green but it is not matter )  I want to add another black square to the image

[image: result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something like Create New, you can do like this.
***You need to add height and width in ImageBackground. You cannot use flex:1 as it wont work.***

```
    <TouchableOpacity>
     <ImageBackground source={YOUR SOURCE} style={{width:100,height:100,alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center', flexDirection:'column'}}>
     <Image source={YOUR OTHER SOURCE} style={{width:30,height:30}} />
     <Text>Send</Text>
    </ImageBackground>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: why I can't use flex :1 ?

Comment: It does not assign the width and height to the background image.